# How to read CSV into specfic objects in a list (Including Ints, Strings, Gender Enum & DOB)

Tags: c#

I was just wondering how I can resolve the issue of VS implying I have not given an argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter of 'id' of 'customer.customer(int, string, string, string, Gender, DateTime)' whilst I have provided all such information and as a side question;

Why is my gender value not letting me turn it from a string to Gender.Male/Gender.Female?

```cs
public static void LoadFromFile()
        {
            List<Customer> customerlst = File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\..\customers.csv")
                                                .Skip(1)
                                                .Select(v => CRM.FromCsv(v))
                                                .ToList();
        }
        public static Customer FromCsv(string csvLine)
        {
            string[] customerlst = csvLine.Split(',');
            Customer customer = new Customer
            {
                ID = int.Parse(customerlst[0]),
                Title = Convert.ToString(customerlst[1]),
                FirstName = Convert.ToString(customerlst[2]),
                LastName = Convert.ToString(customerlst[3]),
                Gender = customerlst[4],
                DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(customerlst[5])
            };
            return customer;
        }
```

Comment: Can you please share the class `Customer `? According to the usage, you need to have a default, parameterless constructor. This is not a constructor call with all the parameters, but like `customer = new Customer(); customer.Prop = Value;` Please see [Enum.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse) for your side question.

Comment: VS isn't "implying". It's telling you the error. You need something like `new Customer(int.Parse(customerlst[0]), customerlst[1], customerlst[2], customerlst[3], int.Parse(customerlst[4]), Convert.ToDateTime(customerlst[5]))` to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your Customer have a default constructor that takes no parameters?
Or should you call it like `new customer(int.Parse(customerlst[0]), Convert.ToString(customerlst[1]), etc.)`

Alternativly you could ass a parameterless constructor for Customer and keep settings your values like you are doing. I'd argue for this being the lesser option though as the constructor would be a good place for verifying the input.

For the `Gender` you can use `Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), customerlst[4])` or preferably `Enum.TryParse`